# c# run command on windows 2008 64bit remotely

Tags: windows, 64-bit, command

I am new to C# coding, please help me out with following, thank you in advance..!!!

I am trying following:

I am developing small C# app to execute batch file on remote servers, following is my code, most of my Servers are windows 2008 64bit, If I RDP into server, I can execute the batch file without any errors, but when I try to do it through following code, it does not work, no exception thrown, but no results.

my batch file contains following command :

```
@ECHO off 
echo Running Remote Commands 
date/t 
time /t 
COPY "\\xt0022\I$\abc\RemoteProcess\testcopy.bat" D:\ab\
date/t 
time /t
```

-

```
try
{
    string remotemachine = "Server1";

    object[] theProcessToRun = { "D:\\ab\\test2.bat" };
    ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
    theConnection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    theConnection.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + remoteMachine + "\\root\\cimv2", theConnection);
    ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

If I debug the code, it shows "Derivation = Function evaluation timed out."

Do I have to run this with RUNAS ..? if Yes.. can anyone help me with those code or method..?

Thank you all..!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into ProcessStartInfo?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("PsExec.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = @"\\<computername -u <username> -p <password> -i c:\\test.bat";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Here's an artice on CodeProject.com that creates a remote process using WMI, like your doing.  Complete source is available.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31113/Create-a-Remote-Process-using-WMI-in-C

This might be a silly question, but what is your timeout set to?  If it's too small, that may be the cause.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same code, here is abother way to look at this issue. If I execute the Batch file which contains local Path in it, it works fine, but if I have Remote file location for it to copy from, it fails :-(, also TimeOut is not set, I am using whatever is default.  do I have to set explicitly more length for timeout..?

Comment: I mean if I do this in Batch file it works fine : COPY "C:\temp\abc.txt" D:\ab\

Comment: So it's timing out getting the file from a remote location.  I have not ran into that issue using a remote command, sorry.